# How to get InfluxDB to accept a self-signed certificate?

Tags: google-chrome, ssl-certificate, certificate, x509certificate, influxdb

I've been trying to get InfluxDB to accept a self-signed certificate, but so for, no luck. I've been following instructions from here:

```
https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.3/security/enable-tls/#configure-influxdb-to-use-tls
```

I created the cert and key with this command:

```
openssl req -x509 -nodes -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout influxdb-selfsigned.key  -out influxdb-selfsigned.crt  -days 9999 -config "C:\OpenSSL\openssl.cnf"
```

The config.yml file is as follows:

```
http-bind-address: ":8087"
tls-cert: influxdb-selfsigned.crt
tls-key: influxdb-selfsigned.key
```

Note, I made the bind port 8087 to ensure it was reading the configuration.

When I start influx from the command line, there are no error messages. Initially there were some TLS handshake errors, but those disappeared, I think when I added the crt and key to the configuration.

However, when I access the URL https://localhost:8087, chrome shows a "not secure" message and I have to click through warnings to get to the site.

To try to get Chrome to trust the certificate, - I followed the instructions from this site:

```
https://www.pico.net/kb/how-do-you-get-chrome-to-accept-a-self-signed-certificate
```

I exported the cert, then re-imported it as trusted.

However, I still get the "not secure" message in Chrome.

Also, the InfluxDB console shows this message:

```
info    http: TLS handshake error from [::1]:63065: remote error: tls: unknown certificate      {"log_id": "0cKnmWB0000", "service": "http"}
```

Any ideas how to get the cert working?

Answer (score 0):

Currently it seems this is no easy way or workaround in open source version. The community has been asking for this feature but no progress yet. See more details [here](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/4090).

However, in Enterprise version, you could configure the server to know you are using self-signed certificates by setting this [configuration](https://docs.influxdata.com/enterprise_influxdb/v1.10/administration/configure/security/enable_tls/) in influxdb-meta.conf file:

```
# If using a self-signed certificate:
https-insecure-tls = true
```